# try catch block in another try catch block

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I have the following scenario:

In my .db.inc.php file I'm connecting to a database:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST . ';dbname=' . DATABASE , USER_DB, PASSWORD_DB);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
}
```

Then I run some functions before I need the connection, but I know that the connection is established as I don't have an error thrown.

Now I need to update my database:

```
include('.db.inc.php');
try {

/...
$sql = "UPDATE de_request_products SET report_id = :report_id WHERE request_id = :request_id";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':report_id', $report_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':request_id', $report_request_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e){
die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
}
```

If above written try block fails, I want to have a try catch block in the Exception Handler to update the database:

```
// ....
catch (PDOException $e){
  try {

   //SEND EMAIL AND

     $sql = "INSERT INTO de_failed_requests (datum, reason) VALUES (:datum, :reason)";
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindValue(':datum', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindValue(':reason', $e->getMessage(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->execute();
   } catch (PDOException $f) {
     die('NOTHING WORKS AT ALL!'. $f->getMessage());
     }
     die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
 }
```

Would this be the way to go or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Why is the `require` inside the `try` and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, the include was in the try because I wrote it wrong here. My question is if this way is efficient or if I should use only one exception handler @kingkero

Comment: This is fine, except that the second `try/catch` isn't going to do anything useful unless you configure `$dbh` to throw exceptions. By default, except for the constructor/connection, PDO errors _silently_. You have to make it use exceptions: `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` Do that right after establishing the connection, in the initial `try/catch` in db.inc.php.

Comment: PDO is odd in that the constructor will always throw an exception, but otherwise you need to make sure it is throwing them, or using PHP's warnings E_WARNING. Its normal behavior is to not complain at all.

Comment: Otherwise, what you've done is fine - you would likely need to handle a query error differently than a connection error, so it makes sense to have them in separate try/catch.

Comment: Side note: Why are you catching the exception when you cannot even connect to the database? What good does it do to continue with any further code in that case? You need to kill your application and fix your database, because it is down. Just echoing an error to screen and then continuing as if nothing happened is not a useful error handling technique in that situation.

Comment: @deceze That's true, but I think it will die as I have "die" in the error exception handler in the connection catch. I'm just creating the app and will include a much more sensitive exception catching for the case that the connection to the database can't be established. There are many connections to the db, if this fails I will get a few emails... :) Can you recommend something better for the first catch block at connection time?

Comment: `$dbh = new PDO(...);` Done. That's all the error handling you need in this case. If this fails, it'll throw an exception, which will kill your app, because you don't catch it. Exactly what you want. Caveat: you'll want to turn off verbose error reporting on your production server to avoid showing your users uncaught exception tracebacks and possibly sensitive information.

Comment: That's an excellente solution. ;) Thank you. The program is running on the command line only and nobody except me will see it, so the errors are only for improving the program when it's in production. Would you still turn them off? I'm very interested in improvements whatsoever @deceze

Comment: If only you are ever going to see them, make them as loud and verbose as possible. A full exception stack trace is much preferable to a dumbed down `$e->getMessage()`. In general: don't catch exceptions, except if you have an actual contingency plan what to do in this exceptional circumstance. You should never need to deal with exceptions in an ideal scenario; if you do see them, that means something is **wrong**. If something is wrong, you want to know about it as loud and clear as possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought about this, too. I will do it this way! Thank you again very much! @deceze